# cgo and pkg-conf and include,build on centos, not found files i include

Tags: go, cgo, pkg-config

```
package xxx

/*
#cgo pkg-config: vips
#include "vips/vips.h"
*/
import "C"
```

When I built my code,it returned "vips/vips.h: No such file or directory".
Centos.
I have installed vips and pkg-conf.But it seems not effect.

Comment: Many distros package the header files separately. Look for a vips devel package of some sort.